# Having two Filters in one table using SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

I want to create two filters in one SlickGrid Table. One will have "input field" based filter where i should be able to put expression, i.e. value > 10 which will give me the results greater than 10 values. The second filter will be the excel like filter where it should be able to list all the values from the first filter result and once user select some values it should show those selected values as result.
Basically, looking for combining result of two filters.

I do have some examples as mentions below

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

http://danny-sg.github.io/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins/examples/example-2-everything.htm

Looking into combining above two filters in one table.
Is it possible to write two filters in one table using SlickGrid? Let me know how to achieve the same.

Comment: what specifically doesn't work?